# How to access $viewValue from controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a an angular app setup as follows. Ng-repeat containing li elements with 2 inputs each (well more than 2 but for this demo I have 2) .

The directive sets the controller.

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="lw in lw_list"   my-lw   ng-model="lw"  >            
    <input my-cell ng-init="init(lane , $index , 'name')"  ng-class="'lib_name inline_div'" type='text'     value="{{ lw.library.name }}" >
    <input my-cell ng-init="init(lane , $index , 'volume')  "ng-class="'number_field'"      type="number"   ng-model='volume' />    
</li>
```

javascript

```
angular.module('Demo').directive("myCell",  function(CellStore){
    return {
            controller : 'CellCtrl' , 
        };
}) ;


angular.module('Demo').controller('CellCtrl' , function($scope , CellStore){
    $scope.init = function(lane, row, column){
        $scope.row = row  ;
        $scope.column = column ; 
        console.log("init" ,  $scope.$parent );
        CellStore.addCell(  lane.lane,  row, column , $viewValue ) ; 
    } ; 
}) ;
```

So the idea is that when each input is created, it will call the init function, which will store the input value in a nested hash (for retrieval later). However I don't know how to access the $viewValue variable (the value that the inputs contain) from within the controller.

Comment: Why don't you just pass 'lw' into the init function?

Comment: That is one way of doing it, but my app has a number of input elements (I only put two here to simplify the example). 

If I could access the model of the input element it would make the code a lot more generic and reusable.

Comment: What about scrapping the controller and doing your init in the link function of the directive? You would have access to all of the current scope. Pass your data in as attributes to the directive.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "scrape the controller". Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Scrap, as in get rid of it and pull that functionality into the link function of the directive. Is there a particular reason you used the controller instead of just doing the initialization in the directive link function?

Comment: Ahhh, Scrap not scrape! 
Still learning angular, and I am not quite sure how the link function works. (I got the impression that it may replace the controller in some way). I'll have a look at the docs and see if that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BoxerBucks says, refactor your code into a `link` function and do the linking from there. You can also do away with the `ng-init` approach as the link function is called when the directive is created.

First, I've altered the directive slightly so it takes the column name in the attribute value of `my-cell` (the `lw` object and the `$index` are both on the scope so there's no need to pass them):

```
<li ng-repeat="lw in lw_list" >            
    <input my-cell="name" ng-class="'lib_name inline_div'" type='text' ng-model="lw.name" >
    <input my-cell="volume" ng-class="'number_field'" ng-model='lw.volume' />    
</li>
```

Then the link function registers this with `CellStore`:

```
app.directive("myCell",  function(CellStore){
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        CellStore.addCell(scope.lw, scope.$index, attrs.myCell);
    };
});
```

And finally, the `addCell` method:

```
app.service('CellStore', function() {
    this.addCell = function(lw, row, column) {
        console.log('add cell:', lw.name, row, column, lw[column]);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lmwj/2/

I wasn't exactly sure on your data structure, but hopefully it's a helpful start.

Answer (score 11):

Others have solved your problem, but I don't see an answer to your main question, which is how to access $viewValue from the controller, if you wanted to do so.

What you're really doing is accessing the instance of [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) that is attached to each input. If you simply put a `name` attribute on your form element and on each input within it, their controllers will then be accessible on the `$scope`. (Since you're using an ng-repeat, you'd need some kind of dynamic naming scheme so you can reach them all. You can also just iterate them.)

Once you've named everything, to get the instance, it's simply:

```
var instance = $scope.formName.inputName;
```

And $viewValue should be at:

```
instance.$viewValue
```

Once you've got this reference, you can also use the other methods on ngModelController, like

```
instance.$setValidity();
```

EDIT: You can play with this, and see how it relates to some validation issues, on [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/xmlilley/pen/gtKay).

Comment: This is a great answer and should be the chosen one...

This comes into play when say you're using ui.bootstrap's typeahead and need to make a custom orderBy or filter function and the $modelValue isn't synced to the $viewValue.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to access it without a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the initialization code in the directive and pass in the the data you need:

```
<input my-cell  ng-class="'lib_name inline_div'" type='text' value="{{ lw.library.name }}" >
```

Then the directive changes to something like this:

```
angular.module('Demo').directive("myCell",  function(){
    return {
            function(scope, element, attrs){}
                 scope.row = row;
                 scope.column = column; 
                 scope.CellStore.addCell(scope.lane.lane, row, column, attrs.value); 
        };
}) ;
```

Since I can't see the rest of your app code, you may need to change some of the variable names to get it to work, but the basic premise is to just use the link function of the directive to run your initialization. Also, in the directive you have access to the inherited scope where your directive is declared.

Comment: OK, I am trying something similar. Assuming I have the link function correct, how do I pass it with the extra arguments from the HTML part of the code?
You have removed the ng-init which was doing that before.

Comment: You can either pick the values straight from the scope or pass them in as attributes and reference them via attrs.<attribute name>